# ListView onItemClickListener does not work Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onitemclick

Ive seen plenty of posts, plenty of tutorials but i can't find the key to make this work. I have a listView with friend requests,as u see these requests have 2 buttons (accept or deny) and i want to know how can i know which button is clicked (At the moment it doesnt even works to tell me if an item is clicked).

Please help, im like desperate.

Heres the code of the Activity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Solicitudes extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String SOLICITUDES_URL = "http://192.168.56.1/webservice/cargarSolicitudes.php";
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private ListView lv;
    // JSON IDS:

    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";

    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private HashMap<String, String> user;
    SessionManager session;

    // array con los amigos
    private JSONArray mAmigos = null;
    // organiza los amigos en una lista.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mAmigosList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_solicitudes);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSolicitudes);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // ListView Clicked
                int itemPosition = position;

                // ListView Clicked
                String itemValue = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                                + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });


    }

    private void updateList() {
        // Para un ListActivity tenemos que tener un List Adapter. Este
        // simpleAdapter
        // utilizará nuestro ArrayList Hashmap actualizado. Utilizo
        // single_request.xml para
        // cada item en la lista y pongo la informaación correcta para cada ID.

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mAmigosList,
                R.layout.single_request, new String[] { TAG_USERNAME },
                new int[] { R.id.textViewAmigoUsuario });

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void updateJSONdata() {
        // Session class instance
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        // get user data from session
        user = session.getUserDetails();
        String username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        mAmigosList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SOLICITUDES_URL, "POST",
                params);

        // cuando parseamos JSON es conveniente hacer un catch de las
        // excepciones

        try {

            mAmigos = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // Iterando para todos los post que nos devuelve el objeto json
            for (int i = 0; i < mAmigos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mAmigos.getJSONObject(i);

                // devuelve el contenido de la etiqueta
                String idUser1 = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);

                // creando un nuevo HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, idUser1);
                // map.put(TAG_ID2, idUser2);

                // agrego el HashList al ArrayList
                mAmigosList.add(map);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // cargando los amigos a través de AsynTask
        new buscarSolicitudes().execute();
    }

    public class buscarSolicitudes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            pDialog.setMessage("Cargando solicitudes...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            updateJSONdata();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            updateList();
        }
    }


}
```

The code of the activity_layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Buscar" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSolicitudes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/solicitudes"
        android:textColor="@color/AzulClaro" />


    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listViewSolicitudes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewSolicitudes"
        tools:listitem="@layout/single_request"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code about the single_request layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/boxSF1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/perfildefecto" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/boxSF2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAmigoUsuario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dip"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnEliminar"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSolicitud"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/denegar"
                        android:max="100" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnAgregar"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnEliminar"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnEliminar"
                        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEliminar"
                        android:background="@drawable/aceptar"
                        android:max="100" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSolicitud"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textViewAmigoUsuario"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="@string/friend_request"
                        android:textColor="@color/AzulClaro" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make your custom adapter and try to handle both Button OnClickListener in Adapter getView().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onItemClicked` is not called because of the `Button`, in your row. Add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root of your  `single_request` layout

Comment: well, i guess im ready to suicide now because this works. But now if u click the Accept buttons or deny in any of the single_requests items, how do i know which one and the position? thanks!

Comment: there is no need to suicide. It is called learning curve. About your second question, accept and deny are buttons. If you want those to respond to a click event you have to set for each of them an `OnClickListener`. So you will have three different behaviours. Two for the buttons and one for the row's click

Comment: and where should i add that OnClickListener? Inside of the onItemClick?im so grateful!

Comment: on the buttonInstance. For instance buttonInstance.setOnClickListener(...). The onClick method will be called from the system when a click event for that button is detected

Comment: ive added this 

aceptar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);
    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(View v)
               {
                   System.out.println("Clicked accept on item"+ itemPosition);
               }
            });

but it only works for the first 'single_request' layout, any ideas? :<

Comment: those buttons are part of the row of the ListView, if I understood correctly, so you have to look for them in the getView's method. You probably need a custom adapter,

Comment: ooh damn.. no idea about how to build one, ill have to look tutorials for that. So much thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

In `single_request` layout you have `focusable` item like `Button` thats why `onItemClick` is not fired. set all `focusable` items focusability `false`.

**code snippet for focusable item like button**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Button" />
```

If you want to set `onClick` of those `Buttons` set it inside your `CustomAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

I have sane issue happen Instead of button try to use ImageView.

now your **single_request_layout** will like.

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="5dp"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/boxSF1"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="2dp"
>         android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/imageUser"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:src="@drawable/perfildefecto" />
>
>         <RelativeLayout
>             android:id="@+id/boxSF2"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_margin="2dp"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             android:padding="5dp" >
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textViewAmigoUsuario"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
>                 android:paddingBottom="2dip"
>                 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
>                 android:paddingTop="6dip"
>                 android:textColor="#333"
>                 android:textSize="16sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:id="@+id/btnEliminar"
>                     android:layout_width="20dp"
>                     android:layout_height="20dp"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSolicitud"
>                     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
>                     android:background="@drawable/denegar"
>                     android:max="100" />
>
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:id="@+id/btnAgregar"
>                     android:layout_width="20dp"
>                     android:layout_height="20dp"
>                     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnEliminar"
>                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnEliminar"
>                     android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
>                     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEliminar"
>                     android:background="@drawable/aceptar"
>                     android:max="100" />
>
>                 <TextView
>                     android:id="@+id/textViewSolicitud"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>                     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>                     android:layout_below="@id/textViewAmigoUsuario"
>                     android:layout_margin="10dp"
>                     android:gravity="left"
>                     android:text="@string/friend_request"
>                     android:textColor="@color/AzulClaro" />
>
>         </RelativeLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

I hope this will work.