# ListView setOnItemClickListener not work

Tags: android, listview

Sorry for my english. I spend many times but i cant fix my problem. I have listView and i want set `setOnItemClickListener` him. This is my listView:

```
 <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id = "@+id/listScene"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                    android:divider="#adb8c2"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:scrollingCache="false"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                    >
                </ListView>
```

Its my code

```
 public void outputListView(ArrayList<String> list) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

but when i click in item its nothing happens

UPD

My item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <service.SwipeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#32777777"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/conditions"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="22dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#25ac36"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#222222"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#66777777"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rooms"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/open_b"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#4fcc54">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Open"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/openText"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/disable_b"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#8e8e8e">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Disable"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/disableT"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/delete_b"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#de5454">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/deleteText"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </service.SwipeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**UPD: simple listView**

**activity_main**.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#adb8c2"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

my **main**

```
  ArrayList<String> asd = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        asd.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item, asd);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

and **item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Its good, its work when i click in item listView, Toast is show position. But i need use `SwipeLayout` then i change code item.xml and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.bottom.smart.detetethis.SwipeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="#32777777"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/conditions"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="22dp"
                        android:text="Active"
                        android:textColor="#25ac36"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:text="Turn light on \n when people arrive"
                        android:textColor="#222222"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="#66777777"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rooms"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Livingroom, Kitechen, Rest room"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/open_b"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#4fcc54">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Open"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/openText"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/disable_b"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#8e8e8e">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Disable"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/disableT"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/delete_b"
                android:layout_width="78dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#de5454">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:id="@+id/deleteText"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.bottom.smart.detetethis.SwipeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

got sick, its not working when i click item listView. But when I get a finger between the clearance item, its work:

[image]

to blame `SwipeLayout`, code `SwipeLayout`:

```
public class SwipeLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private ViewDragHelper viewDragHelper;
    private View contentView;
    private View actionView;
    private int dragDistance;
    private final double AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT = 400.0;
    private int draggedX;

    public SwipeLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SwipeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, -1);
    }

    public SwipeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        viewDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this, new DragHelperCallback());
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        contentView = getChildAt(0);
        actionView = getChildAt(1);
        actionView.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        dragDistance = actionView.getMeasuredWidth();
    }

    private class DragHelperCallback extends ViewDragHelper.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean tryCaptureView(View view, int i) {
            return view == contentView || view == actionView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) {
            draggedX = left;
            if (changedView == contentView) {
                actionView.offsetLeftAndRight(dx);
            } else {
                contentView.offsetLeftAndRight(dx);
            }
            if (actionView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                actionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(View child, int left, int dx) {
            if (child == contentView) {
                final int leftBound = getPaddingLeft();
                final int minLeftBound = -leftBound - dragDistance;
                final int newLeft = Math.min(Math.max(minLeftBound, left), 0);
                return newLeft;
            } else {
                final int minLeftBound = getPaddingLeft() + contentView.getMeasuredWidth() - dragDistance;
                final int maxLeftBound = getPaddingLeft() + contentView.getMeasuredWidth() + getPaddingRight();
                final int newLeft = Math.min(Math.max(left, minLeftBound), maxLeftBound);
                return newLeft;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewHorizontalDragRange(View child) {
            return dragDistance;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
            super.onViewReleased(releasedChild, xvel, yvel);
            boolean settleToOpen = false;
            if (xvel > AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT) {
                settleToOpen = false;
            } else if (xvel < -AUTO_OPEN_SPEED_LIMIT) {
                settleToOpen = true;
            } else if (draggedX <= -dragDistance / 2) {
                settleToOpen = true;
            } else if (draggedX > -dragDistance / 2) {
                settleToOpen = false;
            }

            final int settleDestX = settleToOpen ? -dragDistance : 0;
            viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(contentView, settleDestX, 0);
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(SwipeLayout.this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(viewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        viewDragHelper.processTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        super.computeScroll();
        if(viewDragHelper.continueSettling(true)) {
            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I can not delete it, because I need it in the project. I do not know how to fix this situation

Comment: May be because list-item is consuming click event.

Comment: @Blackbelt i update qestion

Comment: @DhavalPatel no i have not

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033669/listview-onitemclicklistener-does-not-work-android). The property goes in your item.xml

Comment: Visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602924/android-listview-item-click-is-not-working

Comment: Try to add this line in your **MyItem.xml**
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" `
and also chech [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155109/android-list-view-setonitemclicklistener-not-working)

Comment: Keep your code, but start from the beginning again. Try getting another **simple** listview up and running with a simple item. Expand from there, and see what is the issue. Show us that a simple version can work in your environment

Comment: I create simple version and described it in my qestion

Comment: OK, it seems like your `swipeLayout` is capturing your touch event and is NOT propagating that touch event elsewhere. The issue most likely is within `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`. In order for the touch to be processed to the actual list item, you have to return `false` somewhere in the method.

Comment: Just to test. Comment out the code you have in those 2 methods, and just `return false;` instead. I haven't done code like this before, but play around with this.

Comment: @overflowingStack thanks, i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ListView` remove the xml attribute `android:clickable="true"`

This is taking your click event and not sending it down to the child views.

Edit

You are passing in `getApplicationContext()` which is the wrong context. The listener does work, but the Toast is not displaying in the right context. You need to pass in `getContext()`. However, since this is an Activity, you can just pass in `this` instead.

```
public void outputListView(ArrayList<String> list) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.item, list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use `getContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Where is this code? Activity? Fragment? somewhere else?

Comment: Its activity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: pass in `this` instead of  `getApplicationContext()`. You are right, you won't have access to `getContext` but `this` will give you the context you need

Comment: Give us some help with stacktraces.

Comment: try this `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
`

Comment: I use debbuger, when i click item it does not reach here `public void onItemClick`

Comment: why do you set `setItemsCanFocus`?

Comment: I delete `setItemsCanFocus` but the debugger does not want to come on line `public void onItemClick(Ad...` when i click item. Then i delete `android:focusable="false"`, `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in my item.xml but i have same problem

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the ListView click doesn't work. And at this case you might have to add one more attribute.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Add this attribute to the top most layout of your XML where you have provided the ListView elements.

Comment: thank you very much, i spent two days to find your solution